# How to join two SQL queries in SQL Server?

Tags: sql

I have two SQL queries, this is the first one:

```
SELECT Activity, SUM(Amount) AS "Total Amount 2009"
FROM Activities, Incomes
WHERE Activities.UnitName = ? 
  AND Incomes.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
GROUP BY Activity
ORDER BY Activity;
```

Second query:

```
SELECT Activity, SUM(Amount) AS "Total Amount 2008"
FROM Activities, Incomes2008
WHERE Activities.UnitName = ? 
  AND Incomes2008.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
GROUP BY Activity
ORDER BY Activity;
```

How to join these two SQL queries?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: JOIN? Show us some sample result from each query, and also the desired combined result.

Comment: Why do you have different income tables for each year? With one, common income table you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will help you. If your RDBMS Oracle DB use NVL instead of ISNULL.
Use FULL JOIN Because if you have Activity in one Query and this Activity not exist in other you can lost this Activity.
'''SQL

```
SELECT 
 ISNULL(T1.Activity,T2.Activity) AS Activity
,ISNULL(TotalAmount2009,0) AS TotalAmount2009
,ISNULL(TotalAmount2008,0) AS TotalAmount2008
FROM
(select Activity, SUM(Amount) as "TotalAmount2009"
from Activities, Incomes
where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
  Incomes.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
GROUP BY Activity) T1
FULL JOIN 
(select Activity, SUM(Amount) as "TotalAmount2008"
from Activities, Incomes2008
where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
  Incomes2008.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
GROUP BY Activity) T2 
ON T1.Activity=T2.Activity
```

'''

Comment: Tip of today: `COALESCE()` - the ANSI/ISO way do to NVL, ISNULL etc.

Answer (score 0):

use the below query to join two queries.

```
SELECT t1.Activity, t1."Total Amount 2009", t2."Total Amount 2008" FROM(query1) as t1, (query2) as t2 WHERE t1.Activity = t2.Activity
```